# Theory behind conservation of number of free parameters?

Tags: parametrization

It is an often-used rule in mathematics and statistics that if one representation of an object has $n$ "free" parameters, then another representation of that same object requires at least that number of parameters.  E.g. I was just now reading along in [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00561523/document) and came along this sentence:

> A necessary condition is that the number of free parameters be preserved.

as a premise in a proof.

Although this is somewhat intuitive, it seems to me that such a rule is not entirely obvious, especially since the cardinality of $\rm I\!R$ is equal to the cardinality of $\rm I\!R^2$.  However, $\rm I\!R$ is not *homeomorphic* to $\rm I\!R^2$, so perhaps therein lies the meaning of a "number of free parameters".

What is the meta-mathematical basis for this "law of conservation of free parameters"?  Is something like a "law of conservation of free parameters" derivable from ordinary axiomatic systems?  Where can I learn more about the theory of this rule?